# Sorting LINQ 'GroupBy' operator keys into a custom order

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, linq, umbraco

In c#, when using the LINQ operator 'GroupBy' I would like to sort the keys into a specified custom order.

My scenario is football based and i want to sort players into their predefined position (created and set in a CMS). The positions that a player can be assigned are as follows and they can only be grouped into one

- goalkeeper
- defender
- midfielder
- striker

Player.cs (skimmed down)

```
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string ImgUrl {get; set;}
    public string Position {get; set;}
```

PlayersLandingPageViewModel.cs (skimmed down)

```
    public IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, TeamPlayerPage>> GroupedPlayersList { get; set; }
```

PlayersLandingPageController (skimmed down)

```
    var groupedPlayersList = teamPlayersLandingPage.Children<TeamPlayerPage>().GroupBy(x => x.Position);

    var playersLandingPageViewModel = new PlayersLandingPageViewModel(model.Content)
    {
        GroupedPlayersList = groupedPlayersList
    };
```

The above returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, TeamPlayerPage>>` but the keys are in the following order (assume its alphabetical by default?). In the view im just iterating through each group(key) in Model.GroupedPlayersList and then all players within a group. A foreach within a foreach (this works as expected)

- defender
- goalkeeper
- midfielder
- striker

When searching around for a solution, the following post ([how can i create a programmatically sort order in C# on a grouped collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242990/how-can-i-create-a-programmatically-sort-order-in-c-sharp-on-a-grouped-collectio)) suggests using an `IComparer<String>` but through lack of understanding i'm a little unsure how to apply it to work for my scenario. Is it before, with or after the GroupBy action?

```
List<string> playerGroupsSortOrder = new List<string>() { "goalkeeper", "defender", "midfielder", "striker"};
```

Can anyone please recommend anything? An explination or links to help me understand any working solution would be super helpful.

other references

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/320727/how-to-use-the-icomparable-and-icomparer-interfaces-in-visual-c
- This is an Umbraco 8.6 solution that i am working with

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Since position has a finite number of possible values, `enum` seems like a better option than string:

```
enum Position
{
    Goalkeeper,
    Defender,
    Midfielder,
    Striker
}
```

Then because enums are just named integers, you have your order. Goalkeeper = 0, Defender  = 1 etc.

Update your class:

```
public Position Position { get; set; }
```

Then LINQ:

```
teamPlayersLandingPage
    .Children<TeamPlayerPage>()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Position)
    .OrderBy(grp => (int)grp.Key);
```

Comment: Hi, this makes sense. However, before i can try this i will need to work out how to add a new enum data type within umbraco or override the current string property. If you are familiar with umbraco I am using the dropdown data type (which allows string prevalues) and models builder which auto generates the following 

  ///<summary>
  
/// Position: The main position of the player.
///</summary>
  [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Umbraco.ModelsBuilder", "8.1.0")]
  [ImplementPropertyType("position")]
  public string Position => this.Value<string>("position");

Comment: Sorry, I have minimal Umbraco experience I'm afraid.

Comment: No problem, ill figure it out. The most important aspect is that i understand the sorting of the groupBy keys which is clearer now. For now @Dmitry solution worked but I do like the enum approach, it feels cleaner. Ill look further into it. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

If I've understood you right, you can try *mapping*: when sorting you can compute required order (say, 0, 1, 2, 3) for each `Key` ("striker", "defender" etc.) i.e. map `Key` to the required order.

```
  List<string> playerGroupsSortOrder = new List<string>() { 
    "goalkeeper", "defender", "midfielder", "striker"
  };

  ...

  var groupedPlayersList = teamPlayersLandingPage
    .Children<TeamPlayerPage>()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Position)
    .OrderBy(group => playerGroupsSortOrder.IndexOf(group.Key));
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, this makes sense in my mind but I tried it and it doesn't seem to change the order. I am still getting the group ordered as defender, goalkeeper, midfielder, striker.

Comment: @Paul: please, check names (and *cases* `"devender" != "Defender" != "DEFENDER"`): if key is not found `IndexOf` will return unwanted `-1`

Comment: Hi @Dmitry, yes you are correct! This was a casing issue. The prevalues defined in umbraco were uppercase e.g. Goalkeeper, Defender... Once i matched in the code it is now in the correct order. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could use an enum for the player position instead of strings, that way under the hood they will be treated as an int.

```
public enum PlayerPosition
{
    goalkeeper, defender, midfielder, striker
}
```

When I tried it out in a console app it seemed to work if you run order by prior to running the group by.

```
var players = new List<Player>
        {
            new Player { Name = "A", Position = PlayerPosition.midfielder },
            new Player { Name = "B", Position = PlayerPosition.goalkeeper },
            new Player { Name = "C", Position = PlayerPosition.defender },
            new Player { Name = "D", Position = PlayerPosition.midfielder },
            new Player { Name = "E", Position = PlayerPosition.striker },
        };

var result = players.OrderBy(x => x.Position).GroupBy(x => x.Position);
```

Comment: Hey Sam, this feels similar to Johnathans answer. I believe it will work but i need to figure out how to add this within Umbraco. I do like the enum approach, it also keeps that sense of it being strongly typed :)

Comment: I didn't see his answer before typing this out, basically identical to what he suggested. The only difference is the order of the of the groupby & order by statements. I haven't had much to do with Umbraco I'm sorry

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `Dictionary<string, int>` of the position orders from `playerGroupsSortOrder`, then group and sort your list of players using this lookup dictionary for O(1) lookups:

```
var playerGroupsSortOrder = new List<string>() 
{ 
    "goalkeeper", 
    "defender", 
    "midfielder", 
    "striker" 
};

// Create this lookup dictionary here
var playerPositionOrder = playerGroupsSortOrder
    .Select((pos, index) => (pos, index))
    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.pos, kvp => kvp.index);

var sortedGroupPlayerList = teamPlayersLandingPage
    .Children<TeamPlayerPage>()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Position)
    .OrderBy(group => playerPositionOrder[group.Key]);
```

Or just have this dictionary to begin with:

```
var playerPositionOrder = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    { "goalkeeper", 0 },
    { "defender", 1 },
    { "midfielder", 2 },
    { "striker", 3 }
};

var sortedGroupPlayerList = teamPlayersLandingPage
    .Children<TeamPlayerPage>()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Position)
    .OrderBy(group => playerPositionOrder[group.Key]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, using a dictionary also makes sense, ill take a look into this and play around with all the helpful answers :). Thank you!